# Where should I ask a question about custom domain email address

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, email

I'm having trouble setting up a custom domain email address. It is not about programming. It is about what to expect from an email provider (custom domains). Where should I ask this question? It will get closed if I ask it in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your question would be on-topic on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

They generally answer questions about... well... webmastering, which includes hosting, custom domains and email addresses. <sup><sub>I would cite [their tour](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tour) here, however it seems to be rather vague...</sub></sup>

They have tags for [domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains), [emails](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email), and [email addresses](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email-address) <sup><sub>(which should probably should be a synonym)</sub></sup>.

However, before you ask your question I suggest you drop into their [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) <sup><sub>(which doesn't appear to be particularly active)</sub></sup> or ask [on meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Either way, you'll probably be fine to ask your question there. Just make sure it's not opinion based or too broad.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a moderator on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).  I want to clarify that this particular email question would be on-topic because it is about setting up email for your own domain.   So would questions about email marketing for your website.

However, see [this post on webmasters meta](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/are-questions-about-email-hosting-on-topic) discussing whether email hosting questions are on-topic.  John Conde has an excellent answer where he lists the various Stack Exchange sites that might be appropriate for various email questions:

> 1. Software client questions (i.e. What isn't my email software like Outlook working?) belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).
> 2. Server software installation, email server management, and spam filter installation belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).
> 3. Web-based email issues (i.e. sending email via Gmail) belongs on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).
> 4. Coding based email questions (i.e. Why isn't mail mail form sending my email?) belongs at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).
> 5. Cpanel email setup, emails sent marked as spam (either through a website or domain controlled by the user), and sending emails from localhost for development belong at [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).
> 6. Any questions about how what other sites are doing about email or how their email services work are off-topic.