# Where to ask question about email hosting?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the best Stack Exchange site to get feedback on e-mail hosting? In a nutshell, I'm trying to get some feedback on affordable email hosting providers to host 18,000+ e-mail accounts with some usage specifics. I tried asking this question on the Webmasters Stack Exchange as suggested in this meta post: [Where should I ask a question about email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279386/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-email) however my question was put on hold because it apparently appears to be off-topic.

Which Stack Exchange site can I ask this question on?

Note: I have specific requirements and am looking for an objective list of email hosting providers that meet these requirements, so this is not a subjective question.

Comment: please note i'm not really trying to ask a subjective question. i have specific requirements and am looking for a list of known hosting providers that meet those requirements, which is pretty objective

Comment: Your question would not be considered on-topic anywhere on the network. Asking for product/service recommendations is explicitly off-topic everywhere on the network except for two sites specifically designed for recommenations: [hardware recs](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [software recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but your question would fall under neither.

Comment: is there a different site outside stack exchange i can ask this question on? I've spent hours searching the internet to find a hosting provider that meets our requirements and all I've been able to find are services with far more storage space than we actually need that would cost us anywhere from $18,000 to $90,000 per month, which is far outside our company's budget. I could really use some help finding a service that meets our requirements without costing us an arm and a leg

Comment: I mean outside of stackexchange

Comment: Sorry, read your last comment wrong. I'm not sure where else you could ask that.

Comment: Without directly asking for recommendations, you can probably ask how people research and choose services and vendors.

Comment: This is one of the shortcomings of Stack Exchange.  There is no way to get a survey/consensus of expert *opinions* --  an admitedly tricky problem.  You can try Quora.com for this kind of thing. YMMV.

Comment: Well I'd try Quora but people there don't seem to be... well, particularly expert

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, this is a "classic" shopping question. While there's a few sites on the network that tentatively handled these things, there's no really good site on SE for this sort of "service recommendation" questions.

Outside - I'm not sure. The few options I could think of off the top of my head, kind of failed to live up to expectations IMO